# Changing speed variable doesn't change the actual speed of the gameObject in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple gameObject with this script attached. It moves looping through each position, defined with the *currentPos* variable.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PathFollower : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform[] path;
    public float speed = 4.0f;
    public float breakArea = 1.0f;
    public int currentPos = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Debug.Log(speed);
        Vector3 dir = path[currentPos].position - transform.position;
        transform.position += dir * Time.deltaTime * speed;

        if (dir.magnitude <= breakArea)
        {
            currentPos++;
        }
        if (currentPos >= path.Length)
        {
            currentPos = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the gameObject to change speed when i change the speed variable, whereas it doesn't. What's the problem?

Comment: have you tried changing your speed to excessive high numbers, just to make sure it really does not speed it up? Also I would advice you to use the FixedUpdate for movements instead of the regular update. This will lead to smoother movements

Comment: Normalize `dir` vector with `dir.Normalize();`

Comment: I just copied your code and changing the speed variable from the inspector produced the expected outcome. How exactly are you changing the speed variable?

Comment: I'm changing the speed via script. Actually changing it via editor works. Why is that?

Comment: Provide how you are changing it. Right now, you did not put that and we can't help you without that.

Comment: As @Programmer says, maybe you are not accessing the proper game object instance. Let us check how you are scripting that.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the `dir` component before multiplying:

```
dir = dir.normalized; // (or Vector3.Normalize(dir);)
transform.position += dir * Time.deltaTime * speed;
```